# woocommerce admin create order get customer id on create

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

It's been a couple of days now, and I can't seem to find a hook for adding/updating user meta

```
add_user_meta( 'user_id', 'custom_key', 'custom_value');
```

when creating an order in woocommerce admin (**woocommerce->orders->add order**), backend.
Using

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'admin_process_shop_order', 10, 1);
```

This works fine for doing things while the order is processed. However, I need to get the customer ID, which from what I can tell doesn't exist until the order is actually created (makes sense).

So my question is, what hook (or other solution) can I use to get the customer ID once the order is created and searchable with

```
get_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', true);
```

Comment: Try followng hooks with order status,
    `woocommerce_order_status_pending
    woocommerce_order_status_failed
    woocommerce_order_status_on-hold
    woocommerce_order_status_processing
    woocommerce_order_status_completed
    woocommerce_order_status_refunded
    woocommerce_order_status_cancelled`

Comment: A hook executes after payment complete is, `woocommerce_payment_complete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Gugan for your suggestions! It looks like that with your help I was finally able to get this mess sorted  :)

Since I only wanted this to fire one time, i.e. when the order is created (and not again when updated), I hade to combine two actions.

First **'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta'**. Here I can check if the post meta exists (if it does, the order has already been created and should be left alone)

```
function check_order($post_id){
    $new_order = get_post_meta($post_id, '_customer_user', true);
    if(!$new_order){
        add_action('woocommerce_order_status_[MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_STATUS]-processing', 'total_count');
    }
}add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'check_order', 10, 1);
```

If this is a new order move on to **'woocommerce_order_status_[MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_STATUS]-processing'** (with my function **'total_count'**)

```
function total_count($post_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
    $customer_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $user_role = get_user_meta($customer_id, 'wp_capabilities', true);
    $custom = serialize(array('[MY_CUSTOM_USER_ROLE]' => true));
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    if($user_role = $custom){
        $current_total = get_user_meta($customer_id, 'total', true);
        $increment_total = $current_total+1;
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'total', $increment_total);
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last', $today);
    }
}
```

Now I only get an increment on my custom user metas "total" and "last" if this is a new order and if the customer is of my custom user role. Another plus to this is that it will only work for one order status (i.e. in my case **[MY_CUSTOM_ORDER_STATUS]-processing**).

Just jotting down my solution here for anyone else looking to handle similar custom order creation work.